# Use PHP to build Javascript array from MySQL table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to build a set of arrays from a php script for use in Google Chart, and I'm having a little trouble making this work as a stacked column graph. I've been trying to make the query work just by running commands in MySQL Workbench, but I'm having some issues.

What I want the script to do is list each distinct Category, and a series of fields that are a count of the subcats for each category (even if it's 0).

For example, my table looks like this, with somedata showing that there's more in the table:

| category | subcat | somedata |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Blue | Soft | 1123123 |
| Blue | Hard | 1241241 |
| Blue | Hard | 1123123 |
| Red | Cold | 1241241 |
| Red | Hot | 1123123 |
| Green | Sharp | 1241241 |
| Green | Dull | 1123123 |
| Yellow | Rough | 1241241 |
| Yellow | Smooth | 1241241 |
| Yellow | Smooth | 1241241 |

I'm trying to get my query to give me the following data:

| Category | Soft | Hard | Cold | Hot | Sharp | Dull | Rough | Smooth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Blue | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Red | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Green | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Yellow | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 |

Then format it for JavaScript so it appears like this within data (code snippet below):

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

        //list subcategories for chart Legend, append role
        ['Soft', 'Hard', 'Cold', 'Hot', 'Sharp', 'Dull', 'Rough', 'Smooth', { role: 'annotation' } ],

        //formatted arrays for stacked columns 
        ['Red', 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''],
        ['Blue', 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''],
        ['Green', 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, ''],
        ['Yellow', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, '']

   ]);
```

I've been testing simple queries to see how far I can get. So far, it's resulted in the following:

| Category | Soft | Hard | Cold | Hot | Sharp | Dull | Rough | Smooth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Blue | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| Red | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| Green | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| Yellow | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |

I haven't even gotten to the php portion of this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Category, (
SELECT COUNT (Subcat) 
FROM tbl_table 
WHERE Subcat = 'Soft' AND Category = 'Blue'
) 
AS 'Soft', 
#the above portion repeats for each category/subcat combination that's valid
From tbl_table
```

I've tried a few other queries, but didn't have them handy to paste here.

Comment: `WHERE Subcat = 'Soft' AND Category = 'Blue'` the subcat part is fine, but you want the category of this sub query to be equal to the category of the main query instead of hard coded to ‘blue’.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more James?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I use an alias of `t1` to refer to the subquery’s table.  Then you can limit the sub query to the same category as the main query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Category, (
SELECT COUNT (Subcat) 
FROM tbl_table t1
WHERE Subcat = 'Soft' AND t1.Category = tbl_table.Category
) 
AS 'Soft', 
#the above portion repeats for each category/subcat combination that's valid
From tbl_table
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much James! Now to figure out how to make it compatible with the Javascript arrays needed for Google Chats.